# What are the most efficient steps I can take to be accepted into a great PH.D Psychology Program?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I want to get a PhD in psychology. I have a computer Science /minor in math with a 2.9. I worked two jobs while in school (as a software technician and a Calculus tutor) and I have one year experience as a SW engineer outside of school. I am currently 25 years old.

This question is not the same as being a weak student and getting in to a great program. Rather this is a complete shift from major and discipline; while also being semi-borderline.

Comment: Get some research experience in psychology.

Comment: How would this be possible?